# iOS: Dynamically adding a multiline UILabel

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel, autolayout

I am having trouble dynamically adding a multiline UILabel. Here is the result I'm getting:

[image]

I would like the label in the "Summary" box to wrap naturally. Here is the code I'm using to add the label:

```
-(void)setSummary{
    summaryContentLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    summaryContentLabel.numberOfLines=0;
    summaryContentLabel.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    summaryContentLabel.text=self.summary;
    summaryContentLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:13.0];

    [summaryView addSubview:summaryContentLabel];
    [summaryContentLabel  setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(summaryView,summaryContentLabel ,summaryLabel);
    [summaryView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[summaryLabel]-5-[summaryContentLabel(==100)]-5-|" options:nil metrics:nil views:views]];

}
```

You'll notice the title of the book wraps the way I want with no problem. That was done in IB. Unfortunately, I have to add this label in code. Auto Layout is also a requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. I needed to add an additional constraint for the width of the label, like this:

```
[summaryView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[summaryContentLabel]-|" options:nil metrics:nil views:views]];
```

Answer (score 1):

May be I am late but any way I've found solution. You need to explicitly set preferredMaxLayoutWidth for summaryContentLabel. For example:

```
summaryContentLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 200;
```

And I've noticed that if you do the same view layout via xib then interface builder will set preferredMaxLayoutWidth with correct value.

Comment: Can preferredMaxLayoutWidth be set through the Interface Builder?

Comment: Only implicitly. Interface builder sets preferredMaxLayoutWidth with initial label width.

Answer (score -3):

Use this code for multiline label:-

-(void)setSummary
{

```
summaryContentLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
summaryContentLabel.numberOfLines=0;
summaryContentLabel.textAlignment   = UITextAlignmentLeft;
summaryContentLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:13.0];
[summaryView addSubview:summaryContentLabel];

CGSize size = [self.summary sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:13.0] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(240, 99999) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
summaryContentLabel.frame=CGRectMake(72, 22, 240, size.height);  //set the frame according to your need
summaryContentLabel.text=self.summary;
```

}

Answer (score -4):

It doesn't appear that you're actually setting a frame size to your UILabel.  You could always do:

```
CGRectMake(10, 10, 280, 9999);
```

For the height and then to make sure it fits properly instead of being a height of 9999 set:

```
[summaryContentLabel sizeToFit];
```

Comment: I'm using auto layout, so I'm not allowed to call set frame. I'm setting the height of the label in the constraint that I add (it gets set to 100).