# Multiline UILabel with padding in autolayout, in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel, autolayout

I have a UILabel in a UITableView that should be a maximum of 2 lines and have a bit of padding around it (7 left and right and 2 top and bottom). I'm using autolayout and targeting only iOS6 and above. All views are being created and added programatically.

I've subclassed my UILabel, here's the `init` method:

```
- (id)init
{
self = [super init];

self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
self.numberOfLines = 2;
self.backgroundColor = UIColorFromARGB(0x99000000);
self.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0f];

return self;
}
```

If I add this in, I get the right padding, but it makes it just one line:

```
- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect {
UIEdgeInsets insets = {2, 7, 2, 7};
return [super drawTextInRect:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets)];
}
```

I've seen this answer a few times, but it doesn't work for me (no effect):

```
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds limitedToNumberOfLines:(NSInteger)numberOfLines
{
UIEdgeInsets insets = {2, 7, 2, 7};
    return [super textRectForBounds:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds,insets) limitedToNumberOfLines:numberOfLines];
}
```

Does it make a difference that its in a table view? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do any of the solutions in this question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/12901599/558933) help?

Comment: No, I understand how layout constraints work. My issue is the particular combination of a multiline label, with padding, using auto layout (and in a table view, but I suspect that is irrelevant).

Comment: What's it doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you saw in my above comment, you didn't really say what it's doing that you don't expect. I've just done this myself, and this works with autolayout:

```
@implementation InsetLabel

- (void) setInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)insets
    {
    _insets = insets ;
    [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize] ;
    }

- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect
    {
    return [super drawTextInRect:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, self.insets)];
    }

- (void)resizeHeightToFitText
    {
    CGRect frame = [self bounds];
    CGFloat textWidth = frame.size.width - (self.insets.left + self.insets.right);

    CGSize newSize = [self.text sizeWithFont:self.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(textWidth, 1000000) lineBreakMode:self.lineBreakMode];
    frame.size.height = newSize.height + self.insets.top + self.insets.bottom;
    self.frame = frame;
    }

- (CGSize) intrinsicContentSize
    {
    CGSize superSize = [super intrinsicContentSize] ;
    superSize.height += self.insets.top + self.insets.bottom ;
    superSize.width += self.insets.left + self.insets.right ;
    return superSize ;
    }

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@implementation InsetLabel

- (void) setInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)insets
    {
    _insets = insets ;
    [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize] ;
    }

- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect
    {
    return [super drawTextInRect:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, self.insets)];
    }

- (void)resizeHeightToFitText
    {
    CGRect frame = [self frame];
    CGFloat textWidth = frame.size.width - (self.insets.left + self.insets.right);

    CGSize newSize = [self.text sizeWithFont:self.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(textWidth, 1000000) lineBreakMode:self.lineBreakMode];
    frame.size.height = newSize.height + self.insets.top + self.insets.bottom;
    self.frame = frame;
    }

- (CGSize) intrinsicContentSize
    {
    CGSize superSize = [super intrinsicContentSize] ;
    superSize.height += self.insets.top + self.insets.bottom ;
    superSize.width += self.insets.left + self.insets.right ;
    return superSize ;
    }
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self resizeHeightToFitText];
}
```

This works even better imho.